# Finding the solution to $u_{xx} - au_x = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So as above, I am trying to find the general solution to:

$$u_{xx} - au_{x} = 0$$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ Also, it should match the boundary conditions $$u(0,t) = 1, \quad u(1,t) = 0$$

It is not quite for an assignment, but I had a test a week prior that required the solution to this, and I was not able to obtain it. I still could not find the solution after some searching online, so any advice would be great.

Comment: Hint: $(u_x-au)_x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v=u_x$

Then you just have $v_x=av$ which is a simple exponential differential equation.

Comment: Thanks for that - it does indeed solve the ODE. I am trying to match it with the boundary conditions $$u(0,t) = 1, u(1,t) = 0$$ though. Perhaps I should have put this in.

Comment: If you carry on to find the general solution to this ODE, this it is fairly straightforward to plug in values to get the function to agree to the boundary conditions. What part are you struggling with?

Comment: Ah yes, I can find values such that it will agree with the BCs. I realize that I have not explained my problem enough, so I will close the problem (which by definition is solved) for now. My actual problem is solving for a PDE with those boundary conditions, and homogenizing the boundary conditions pertaining to $$v(x,t) = u(x,t) - u^{ss}(x)$$.

Comment: Well I wish I could help but I know little to nothing about PDEs so I can't give any further advice

Comment: Thanks for your help though! Using the substitution $v = u_x$ was something I entirely forgot about - so it is good to have a reminder about that.